# integration wrt to a function

Tags: integration

I was checking some papers and I learned that the following expression is valid.

$\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)d(g(x)) = \int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) g'(x) dx $.

It seems to help solving integrals when complicated terms involved.

But I am not sure whether the following is correct.

$\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)d(g(x)) = - \int_{0}^{\infty} g(x) d(f(x)) $

Can anyone enlighten me about it? Thank you.

Comment: Think of it as a generalization of integration by parts.  You need an additional term (rhs) of $f(x)g(x)]_0^\infty$

Comment: Have you tried any examples?  Often it is very easy to see that something is not true by actually doing a couple of computations.

Comment: @herbsteinberg thank you so much, I see how it works now.

Comment: @XanderHenderson that's right. I was trying to understand someone else's work, I thought I did not know some steps. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not correct. Take $f(x)=1$ for all $x$ and $g(x)=e^{-x}$ for a counter-example.